# Ruby (Rails) unescape a string -- undo Array.to_s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, string, http-headers

Have been hacking together a couple of libraries, and had an issue where a string was getting 'double escaped'.

for example:
**Fixed example**

```
 > x = ['a']
 => ["a"] 
 > x.to_s
 => "[\"a\"]" 
 >
```

Then again to

```
\"\[\\\"s\\\"\]\"
```

This was happening while dealing with http headers.  I have a header which will be an array, but the http library is doing it's own character escaping on the array.to_s value.

The workaround I found, was to convert the array to a string myself, and then 'undo' the to_s.  Like so:
formatted_value = value.to_s

```
if value.instance_of?(Array)
  formatted_value = formatted_value.gsub(/\\/,"") #remove backslash                                                 
  formatted_value = formatted_value.gsub(/"/,"")  #remove single quote
  formatted_value = formatted_value.gsub(/\[/,"") #remove [                                                                                                     
  formatted_value = formatted_value.gsub(/\]/,"") #remove ]   
end
value = formatted_value
```

... There's gotta be a better way ... (without needing to monkey-patch the gems I'm using).  (yeah, this break's if my string actually contains those strings.)

Suggestions?

** UPDATE 2 **

Okay.  Still having troubles in this neighborhood, but now I think I've figured out the core issue.  It's serializing my array to json after a to_s call.  At least, that seems to be reproducing what I'm seeing.

['a'].to_s.to_json

I'm calling a method in a gem that is returning the results of a to_s, and then I'm calling to_json on it.

Comment: Your example with `x.to_s` causing the formatting that you are showing is not normal behavior. Why would a string be converted into an array? Did you override something that you're not telling us about here?

Comment: I think you should clarify your question and/or add more examples of "double escaping". Double quotes have to be escaped if you want to put them into a double quoted string.

Comment: I'm equally confused.  I do your example in `irb` and don't get your results at all (didn't really expect to).  Why would the string be turned into an array automatically?

Comment: What version of ruby are you getting this behaviour with?  As @jdl mentioned, `x.to_s` doesn’t have the behaviour you are describing, be it with ruby 1.8.7, ruby 1.9.2, or jruby.

Comment: thanks guys,  very sorry, copy paste error in the example -- now fixed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've edited my answer due to your edited question:

I still can't duplicate your results!

```
>> x = ['a']
=> ["a"]
>> x.to_s
=> "a"
```

But when I change the last call to this:

```
>> x.inspect
=> "[\"a\"]"
```

So I'll assume that's what you're doing?

it's not necessarily escaping the values - *per se*.  It's storing the string like this:

```
%{["a"]}
```

or rather:

```
'["a"]'
```

In any case.  This should work to un-stringify it:

```
>> x = ['a']
=> ["a"]
>> y = x.inspect
=> "[\"a\"]"
>> z = Array.class_eval(y)
=> ["a"]
>> x == z
=> true
```

I'm skeptical about the safe-ness of using `class_eval` though, be wary of user inputs because it may produce un-intended side effects (and by that I mean code injection attacks) unless you're very sure you know where the original data came from, or what was allowed through to it.

Comment: thank you.  I definitely messed up the example in the question